# Creating reusable Arel blocks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arel

So I am drawing a lot of graphs/analytics from my database that require non-trivial SQL to get their data. I've done v1 by just writing lots of raw SQL, and now I'd like to convert this into Arel.

A lot of the queries have large blocks of repeated code. As a simple example, I very often want to get data on all of the `Lists` for a given `Org`. In Arel this is:

```
loads_of_other_arel.where(lists_table[:org_id].eq(@org.id))
```

I would like to factorise the repetition of `lists_table[:org_id].eq(@org.id)` to something like:

```
loads_of_other_arel.filter_lists_by_org
```

This could be done by:

```
def filter_lists_by_org arel
  arel.where(lists_table[:org_id].eq(@org.id))
end
```

and then calling `filter_lists_by_org(loads_of_other_arel)`, but this seems very procedural, and not what we should be doing as good OO programmers. So it seems like I will have to open up some of the existing Arel classes and monkey-patch some methods onto them. This is more OO, but feels like overkill - should I even be thinking about doing this, or should I just repeat the Arel in every method?

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you're asking. It would seem you're just talking about chainable scopes. If you clean up your question a bit more I can try and answer it. That said, if what you're going for is good Object-oriented design, then you probably shouldn't be using Arel/ActiveRecord at all. Peppering ad-hoc querying logic throughout your application just tightly couples your entire application to your persistence layer. I would look into something like the Repository Pattern. [Minimapper](https://github.com/joakimk/minimapper) is a nice implementation of the pattern for SQL.

Comment: Hmmm thanks, I think scopes might actually be the answer somehow, although I'd assumed they weren't. I think I might be doing a bunch of stuff that the AR Query Interface can't handle sensibly, but I'll make super sure of that before going any further.

Answer (score 1):

I typically use scopes for this. Here is a contrived example:

```
scope :filtered_by_org, ->(org_id) {where(lists_table[:org_id].eq(org_id))}

loads_of_other_arel.filtered_by_org(@org.id)
```

Reading over the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods/scope) would help drive the point home.

Comment: You could even extract the scopes into a module and include it in different classes.

Comment: Interesting! Although I don't think Arel and ActiveRecord scopes are able to interact in that way - if you do a bunch of Arel then you can't call a named scope on that Arel.